# Sed substitute input by first matching argument

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I'm trying to get some sed command to work without success...

```
echo -e "This.Is.a.Test.V03.r501.dump" | sed  "s/^\(\w+(\.\w+)*\)\.V[0-9]{2}.*$/\1/g"
```

Basically, I want to match and return `This.Is.a.Test` while this `\.V[0-9]{2}` is fixed, but instead it returns the whole input string.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches alphanumerics, you are looking to capture only alphabets, so replace `\w` with `[:alpha:]`. Additionally `{2}` needs to be replaced with `\{2\}`. The following works with GNU `sed`

```
 echo -e "This.Is.a.Test.V03.r501.dump" | 
 sed  "s/^\([[:alpha:].]\+\)\.V[0-9]\{2\}.*$/\1/g"
 This.Is.a.Test
```

Comment: This is even closer than the answer provided by @Ziffusion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
echo -e "This.Is.a.Test.V03.r501.dump" | sed -e  "s/\(.*\)\.V[0-9]*.*/\1/"
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for! Just a quick question tho, would you know why it doesn't work with `"s/\(.*\)\.V[0-9]{2}.*/\1/"` ?

Comment: You have to use a regular expression syntax that sed understands. It is not the same as other programs. In fact, just remember that there is no standard syntax. Always consult the docs for the particular program you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `sed`

```
sed  -r 's/^(([^.]+.){3})([^.]+).*/\1\3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

One way is to use awk

```
$ echo "This.Is.a.Test.V03.r501.dump" | awk -F'.' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{NF=4}1'
This.Is.a.Test
```

Comment: Prbl with that command is that you need to know how many word seperated by a dot you want to output

Comment: well, yes, but that wasn't exactly clear from the question so I guessed :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl This is true for `GNU awk` only.